# pycurl https error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, pycurl

[image: Screenshot of the error]

```
>>> import pycurl
>>> c = pycurl.Curl()
>>> c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://quora.com')
>>> c.perform()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pycurl.error: (60, 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate')
>>>
>>> c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://quora.com')
>>> c.perform()
>>>
>>>
```

Why is it unable to get local issuer certificate? How do I solve this? When I open quora.com in my browser, I see that its identity is verified. Why is this the case? How do I get pycurl to use the same certificates my browser uses?
[image]

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332643/pycurl-and-ssl-cert

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that `pycurl` needs an up-to-date certificate chain to verify the ssl certificates.

A good solution would be to use [certifi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi).

It's basically an up-to-date copy of mozilla's built in certificate chain wrapped in a python package which can be kept up to date using pip. `certifi.where()` gives you the location to the certificate bundle.

To make `pycurl` to use it, set the `CAINFO` option:

```
import pycurl
import certifi

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://www.quora.com')
curl.perform()
```